# Retrieve birthdays and genders from people API in server side with token generated client side

Tags: node.js, google-people-api

I would like to retrieve birthday and gender from google people API in my backend nodejs server.
The access token is generated client side with those 2 scopes:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

The client sends the accessToken and the server queries the people API in the following way :

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
async function getDataFromPeopleAPI(googleId, accessToken) {
    try {

        let params = {
            resourceName: `people/${googleId}`,
            personFields: 'birthdays,genders',
            access_token: accessToken //generated by client
        };
        let res = await google.people({
            auth: GOOGLE_API_KEY //API key
        }).people.get(params);
        let {birthdays, genders} = res.data;

    } catch (e) {

    }
};
```

The issue is that even though my birthday is set as public and my gender the people api always returns the same result . I don't receive any error code but I never receive the data I want. Here is the response I get:

```
  "resourceName": "people/102865456870877320332",
  "etag": "%EgUBBwg3LhoEAQIFBw=="
}
```

What am I doing wrong when querying the people API ? 
Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried using `'people/me'` ?

Answer (score 0):

This might be too old to answer, but here is the correct format of the request:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

let userData = await google
  .people({
    version: "v1", // mention the API version
    auth: process.env.GOOGLE_SERVER_API_KEY,
  })
  .people.get({
    resourceName: "people/me", // not people/${googleId}
    personFields: "genders,birthdays", // mention your scopes
    access_token: accessToken, // generated by client
  });
```

Refer to this URL for scope documentation:
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get